# Foreign Key error SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have three tables that are to be connected using a foreign key.

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
    customerID INT,
    lastname VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    firstname VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT phoneCheck CHECK ((phone LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')),
    category VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT categoryDefault DEFAULT 'A',
    CONSTRAINT categoryCheck CHECK (category IN ('A', 'B', 'C')),

    CONSTRAINT customerPK
        PRIMARY KEY (customerID)
)


CREATE TABLE booking
(
    customerID INT,
    packageCode VARCHAR(6) UNIQUE,
    bookingDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    amountPaid MONEY CONSTRAINT amountPaidDefault DEFAULT 0.00,

    CONSTRAINT bookingPK
        PRIMARY KEY (customerID),

    CONSTRAINT bookingFK
        FOREIGN KEY (customerID)
        REFERENCES customer (customerID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE package
(
    packageCode VARCHAR(6),
    destination VARCHAR(70),
    CONSTRAINT packageCodeCheck CHECK (packageCode LIKE ('YFK%')),
    price MONEY NOT NULL CONSTRAINT priceCheck CHECK ((price BETWEEN 1000 AND 10000)),
    passportRequired VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT passportRequiredDefault DEFAULT 'Y',
    CONSTRAINT passportCheck CHECK (passportRequired IN ('Y', 'N')),

    CONSTRAINT packagePK
        PRIMARY KEY (packageCode),

    CONSTRAINT packageFK
        FOREIGN KEY (packageCode)
        REFERENCES booking (packageCode)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

I got the Foreign key between customer and booking set properly, its purpose is to delete all associated bookings with that customer. I am currently trying to do the same between package and bookings, When a package record is deleted, it should also delete the corresponding records. I continue to get the error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "packageFK". The conflict occurred in database "travel", table
>   "dbo.booking", column 'packageCode'.

Im not quite sure what this is referencing as I have encountered this error before and fixed it, unfortunately... I cannot in this case.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: There error simply means that you're trying to insert a value into `package.packageCode` that is **NOT** present in the referenced table, in `booking` in the `packagecode` column.....

Comment: That error would mean you do not have a package code in booking which matches the one you are inserting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to delete all booking rows when a package is deleted, the package table must be the primary table and the booking table must reference the package table. Remove the foreign key constraint from the table and add the following to the bookings table:

```
CONSTRAINT booking_packageFK
    FOREIGN KEY (packageCode)
    REFERENCES package (packageCode)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

You should also remove the UNIQUE constraint from the packageCode on the booking table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have your foreign key relationship set up correctly even between Customer and Booking.
In your `Create Table customer` following tells the server that CustomerId is the Primary Key in customer table:

```
CONSTRAINT customerPK
        PRIMARY KEY (customerID)
```

In your `Create Table booking` following tells the server that CustomerId is the Primary Key as well as a Foreign Key that references customer:

```
 CONSTRAINT bookingPK
        PRIMARY KEY (customerID),

    CONSTRAINT bookingFK
        FOREIGN KEY (customerID)
        REFERENCES customer (customerID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Similarly in your package table you have set packageCode as both primary and foreign key.

What I think you need is:

1. `CustomerId` in `Customer` table should be the primary key
2. There should be a `BookingId` and a `CustomerId` in the `Booking` table. `BookingId` will be the primary key and `CustomerId` will be the foreign key that references `Customer`.
3. There should be a `BookingId` in the `Package` table. It will be a foreign key that references `Booking`.